# How to (totally) stop the clipboard collection (in Microsoft word)?

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard

When I use Ctrl+C in Word (2003) it opens the clipboard collection basket.

I want it turned off, completely, always.

Is there a way to do it? (I wasn't able to find it)

Comment: Show Office Clipboard Automatically and Show Office Clipboard When CTRL+C Pressed Twice have no difference???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. On the Clipboard task pane, click Options.
2. Clear the "Show Office Clipboard Automatically" check box.
3. Clear the "Show Office Clipboard When Ctrl+C Pressed Twice" check box.

Note: To copy items to the Clipboard while it is turned off, select the "Collect Without Showing Office Clipboard" check box.

Source: MS Office Help File

Comment: This doesn't stop it. It stops it from showing.

Comment: This does NOT prevent Office from catching, storing and unveiling the history of your clipboard. It only hides the message in the bottom-right corner.